# Findcontrol in LoginView LoggedInTemplate on page load?

Tags: asp.net, loginview

I have a LoginView with an Anonymous Template and a LoggedInTemplate. And i wanna find out the control contained in LoggedInTemplate on page load event.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
               <%-- <span >--%>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgUserPic" CssClass="profilePic floatRight cursor" runat="server" />
                        <a href="#"  class="hlnkstyle">                            
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLoginUser" runat="server" class="show_hide"/>
                        </a>
                    <%--</span>--%> 
                    <div class="slidingDiv  imgHover">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgSlidingUserPic" CssClass="slidingPic" runat="server" />
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" />
                        <br /><asp:Label ID="lblEmail"  ForeColor="#666" runat="server" />                       
                        <br /><br />
                        <asp:HyperLink id="hlkUsrProfile" CssClass="lnkprofilestyle" runat="server">View Profile</asp:HyperLink>
                        <div class="innerSlidingDiv">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlkUsrAccount" NavigateUrl="~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx" runat="server">Account</asp:HyperLink>
                            <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" style=" float:right;" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"
                                onloggingout="HeadLoginStatus_LoggingOut"/> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>                                           
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

Here i am trying to find the controls(Hyper Link & Image) in Log In View on page load event.
    But with this code i am unable to get the control and getting an error.
    so any help is deeply appreciated.

```
 HyperLink hlkUsrProfile = (HyperLink)HeadLoginView.FindControl("hlkUsrProfile");
        Image imgUserPic = (Image)HeadLoginView.FindControl("imgUserPic");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(this.HeadLoginView.FindControl("hlkUsrProfile") as HyperLink).Text = "Some text";
(this.HeadLoginView.FindControl("imgUserPic") as Image ).ImageUrl= "Image Url";
```